# JIRA - [XRAY]- How to batch append tests from one existing test plan to another existing test plan

Tags: jira, test-plan, jira-xray

I have two test plans with a lot of tests.  I want to select all in one test plan, and add these tests to another existing test plan, leaving the second with all the original tests plus the ones appended from the first.

When I select all the tests in the first test plan, there are options to create a test execution, a test set, but nothing to add to test plan (which is what you see if you are in the testing board)

I don't want to have to open each test individually and add it to the second test plan, as I already have them in a list in the first one. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do what you are searching for, that is adding tests from one Test Plan to another:

1. Create a Filter that will have all the tests that you want to add and then add those using the *Add Tests* option like below:
   [image]
2. Add those tests to a Test Set and then add the Tests to the Test Plan through the Test Set, like below:
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, thats done it for me! :)